call PyObject_VectorcallMethod , TypeError: Class.set_params() got multiple values for argument 'a'
Python code
class Class:
      a = 10
      b = 20
      c = 30
       
      def set_params(self, a, b=-60):
          print("set_params(a={}, b={})".format(a, b))
          self.a = a
          self.b = b

part of the C code (full code): imitation of the python code ob.set_params( a=77 , b = 20):
PyObject *name = Py_BuildValue("s", "set_params");
PyObject *kwnames = Py_BuildValue( "(s,s)", "a", "b");
PyObject *keyfunc = Py_BuildValue( "i", 77, "i", 20);
PyObject *args[] = { pInstance, keyfunc };
    
size_t nargsf = 2 | PY_VECTORCALL_ARGUMENTS_OFFSET;
PyObject *ret = PyObject_VectorcallMethod(name, args, nargsf, kwnames);
Py_DECREF(keyfunc);
Py_DECREF(kwnames);
Py_DECREF(name);


C code:
puts("set_params(self,77,b=88,d=99)");
PyObject *name = Py_BuildValue("s","set_params");
PyObject *kwnames = Py_BuildValue( "(s,s)", "b","d");   // list names of parameters: b=88,d=99) 
PyObject *keyfunc = Py_BuildValue( "i",77);
PyObject *a2 = Py_BuildValue( "i", 88);             // value of arg2 "b"
PyObject *a3 = Py_BuildValue( "i", 99);             // value of arg3 "d"
PyObject *args[] = { pInstance, keyfunc, a2,a3 };   // list arguments     set_params(self,77,b=88,d=99)


size_t nargsf = 2 | PY_VECTORCALL_ARGUMENTS_OFFSET;
PyObject *ret = PyObject_VectorcallMethod(name , args, nargsf , kwnames);
Py_DECREF(keyfunc);
Py_DECREF(kwnames);
Py_DECREF(name);
Py_DECREF(a2);
Py_DECREF(a3);

output:
set_params(self,77,b=88,d=99)
a: 77
b: 88
c: 0
d: 99


more examples at https://github.com/akalend/PythonApiExample

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
